# people picker, on edit page, display on published page as hyperlink

Tags: javascript, page-layout, person

Basically I have a people picker like so in my page layout `<SharePointWebControls:UserField ID="UserField2" runat="server" FieldName="Approver"/>`
 this shows in the edit page and when it is published the name inputted shows on the published page. However not as a link. How do I get it to show it as a link to the mysites page of the person. I am using SP13